# How to create persistent header in MVC web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I am working on angularJS project right now, and on login of a user want to set my custom header value with UserID and name to be presistent. IS it possible to presist header enven after browser restart?

one of my last tries was this code:

```
var tokenIdentity = new AuthCacheManager().Authenticate(loginName, password);
//  HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Last-Update", "AuthToken");

response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tokenIdentity);

response.Content = new StringContent("asdasd", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"), "text/xml");
response.Headers.Add("AuthToken", tokenIdentity.ToString());
response.Content.Headers.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10.0);
response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", "{ab:a}");
response.Headers.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
response.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "timeout = 20000 max = 100");

return response;
```

But it didn't work at all.

Does anyone know how to make a header persistent since what i am doing now is only alive for one request?

Comment: Do you mean you want a header that you added in one response to also be sent in later responses. There's no way to do that. If you want the header to be sent on multiple responses, then send it on multiple responses.

Comment: Okay, then coockies i my best choise, since i cant use sessions?

Comment: Why can't you use sessions? Sessions _use_ cookies to store the session ID.

Comment: Because i use WEb Api it will be pretty hacky way to implement it.

Comment: Why? It would be exactly like any other use of cookies with Web API. If necessary, I suppose you could create a session state provider which took the session id from a custom header; but you would still have to send that header with every response, and your consumers would have to send it back to you on every request. That's pretty much the definition of a cookie, except that you would only have to send it to the client once per session.

Comment: Also, consider what's going on with the standard `Authentication` header - the consumer needs to send it with every request.

Comment: Ive already implemented caching to solve this problem with multiple redudant requests if user exsists to db. Now im just in need of a easy way to keep one single guid on Client side, for case if i have to restart server, so i could renew UserCach afterwards.

Comment: Cookies are the only persistence mechanism I know of which depends only on HTTP.